# How to increase the maximum audio output power

Tags: android, audio, volume

Once I did dig into Android programing and find the interface `AudioTrack.setStereoVolume(lv,rv)` to set the output audio power.  But the problem is that  it just adjusts the volume within the range that the cellphone vendor specifies in its system.

How can I change that range within the Android system with NDK or something else? I want to make my phone able to output more power to help people with weak hearing to catch music or ringtone.

Comment: There will almost always be some filters running at the platform level that determines the maximum output level (e.g. companders or peak limiters). There are even some phones that have a "speaker protection"-functionality in the hardware codec block, to avoid damaging the speakers. Where the parameters for these filters are stored, and the format in which they are stored varies between different platforms.

Comment: If they put a power limit do not cross it. That said you could take an amp like vmoda sells (or cheaper) and add a speaker...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only possible to increase the volume of your device out of the range specified by the vendor and have good sound, when you have root access on the device. But you have to be careful with increasing the volume out of the range specified by the vendor, so that you don't damage the speaker. Or doing this can also decrease the lifetime of your speakers and your device. So, I think it's not a very good idea to do this.

But, I've found an how-to how you can increase the volume out of the specified range (not tested by my own) if you have root access on your device:
http://androidadvices.com/increase-volume-android-mobile-phones/

Good luck!

Kr

Comment: thx, it looks like feasible way.  make an app to get root right and finish the left steps to adjust the max volume range... let me try it.

Comment: The information on the linked page is platform-specific. It's likely to fail on anything except some of HTC's phones.